# How do I reverse order of simplexmlelement list?

Tags: php, xml

I have a simplexml object like this

```
<aaaa>
    <bbbb>0000</bbbb>
    <cccc>0000</cccc>
    <dddd>
        <eeee>
          <gggg>1111</gggg>
          <hhhh>2222</hhhh>
          <mmmm>3333</mmmm>
        </eeee>
        <eeee>
          <gggg>4444</gggg>
          <hhhh>5555</hhhh>
          <mmmm>6666</mmmm>
        </eeee>
        <eeee>
          <gggg>7777</gggg>
          <hhhh>8888</hhhh>
          <mmmm>9999</mmmm>
        </eeee>
    </dddd>
</aaaa>
```

How can I do to obtain a new structure like the following? (new element ffff containing same list of children of dddd in reverse order)

```
<aaaa>
    <bbbb>0000</bbbb>
    <cccc>0000</cccc>
    <dddd>
        <eeee>
          <gggg>1111</gggg>
          <hhhh>2222</hhhh>
          <mmmm>3333</mmmm>
        </eeee>
        <eeee>
          <gggg>4444</gggg>
          <hhhh>5555</hhhh>
          <mmmm>6666</mmmm>
        </eeee>
        <eeee>
          <gggg>7777</gggg>
          <hhhh>8888</hhhh>
          <mmmm>9999</mmmm>
        </eeee>
    </dddd>
    <ffff>
        <eeee>
          <gggg>7777</gggg>
          <hhhh>8888</hhhh>
          <mmmm>9999</mmmm>
        </eeee>
        <eeee>
          <gggg>4444</gggg>
          <hhhh>5555</hhhh>
          <mmmm>6666</mmmm>
        </eeee>
        <eeee>
          <gggg>1111</gggg>
          <hhhh>2222</hhhh>
          <mmmm>3333</mmmm>
        </eeee>
    </ffff>
</aaaa>
```

I've tried to iterate children of dddd and insert them into an array of objects to be reversed with array_reverse... but when I try to insert the objects back in the main structure, the result is broken/incomplete

Comment: "but when I try to insert the objects back in the main structure, the result is broken/incomplete" - elaborate this

Comment: Have you looked at XSLT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over those child elements and insert them into the new `<ffff>` element in the correct order.

This is most easily done by mixing your existing `SimpleXMLElement` usage with the extra functionality available with the [**DOM extension**](http://php.net/dom). No need for intermediate arrays or sorting them.

```
$aaaa = simplexml_load_string($xml_string);

// Add new <ffff> element
$ffff = $aaaa->addChild('ffff');

// Get DOMElement instance for <ffff>
$ffff_dom = dom_import_simplexml($ffff);

// Loop over <dddd> children and prepend to <ffff>
foreach ($aaaa->dddd->children() as $child) {
    $child_copy = dom_import_simplexml($child)->cloneNode(TRUE);
    $ffff_dom->insertBefore($child_copy, $ffff_dom->firstChild);
}

// Go back to SimpleXML-land and see the result
echo $aaaa->saveXML();
```

([See this example running online.](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ra8cYR))

Comment: Great! I've been trying to use an hybrid solution but I'm very bad with the dom extension... thank you very much.